# How to read Mifare Classic 1k ISO 14443-3A card details?

Tags: ios, .net, maui, core-nfc

Developing an application to read card details using NFC. Actually, it's a cross-platform (MAUI) app, but it implements the code in native.

ISO 14443-4 cards are working fine when tap a card "DidDetectTags" method hitting. For the mentioned Mifare card it's not working.

Tried in NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate and NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate.

Also in the info.plist configured below keys

```
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
    <array>
    <string></string> //Confirured more than 200+ keys
    </array>

<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
        <string>TAG</string>
        <string>NDEF</string>
    </array>
```

Testing device : iPhone 7 plus, iOS : 15.8

I am suspecting selector identifier may not configured correctly for mifare classic 1k card, can anyone help me on this what i am missing?

Tried with different identifier but no luck.

Comment: As of my expirience Mifare Classic cards with "frabric settings" are totally empty and do have no "Compatibility Container" ("CC") preinstalled, so when trying to get a NDEF formatted response your app gets no "intent" = data.

Comment: @MichaelFehr Sorry for the late response. For me even "DidDetectedTags" methods not hitting in both NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate and NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate. Any inputs would be helpful. Thanks